# Add another language to the website

Tags: html

first of all I would like to declare that I'm an absolute amature in programming. I'm doing this for school.

What I want to do is a create an icon in the top corner, like for example the Swedish flag, and when they press on it, it will rederict to my "swedish" version.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an image with a link like this:

```
<a href="/sw">
    <img src="/flag.png">
</a>
```

The /sw is the directory you are redirecting them to, if you have a folder called "swedish" then change /sw to /swedish (be sure it is in the main website folder)

The /flag.png is the image you are using. If you have your image in a folder then use /foldername/flag.png.

You can also add classes like this:

```
<a class="language_link" href="/sw">
    <img class="swedish_flag" src="/flag.png">
</a>
```

I do recommend putting this code in a div and giving the div a class:

```
<div class="image_holder">
    <a class="language_link" href="/sw">
        <img class="swedish_flag" src="/flag.png">
    </a>
</div>
```

You can manipulate the classes with css, look on stackoverflow where to find css guides if you don't know how to use it. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

maybe this will work

```
<a href="your_swedish_version"><img src="your_flag"></a>
```

Comment: My opinion is that this is not good enough to be a answer.. _Also avoid saying **maybe**, that sounds like you are not sure about it._